# merging outputs data within macro

Tags: sas

I have sas question. I am applying the same analyses to the 3 files that I am reading in using macro. My challenge is how to merge the 3 files within the macro. I am wondering if anyone has an idea. Please see the codes below.

```
%macro data(sub);

data &sub._err1;
set &sub._err;
 keep pasecure flag1;
 run;

proc sort data=&sub._err1; by pasecure; run;

data new;
merge;
by pasecure;
run;

%mend data;
%data(Alg);%data(Bio);%data(Lit);run;
```

Thanks for your time and inputs,

Comment: You have three datasets which you want to do the same first data step and sort to, and then merge the results together?

Answer (score 0):

```
%macro data(sub1, sub2, sub3);

%do i=1 %to 3;
  data &&sub&i.._err1 (rename=(flag1=flag_&&sub&i..));
  set &&sub&i.._err;
  keep pasecure flag1;
  run;

  proc sort data=&&sub&i.._err1; by pasecure; run;
%end;

data new;
merge %do i=1 %to 3; &&sub&i.._err1 %end;;
by pasecure;
run;

%mend data;
%data(Alg,Bio,Lit);
```

Or more flexible:

```
%macro data(sub=);

%let sub_out=;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&sub.));
  %let tbl=%scan(&sub.,&i.);
  data &tbl._err&i (rename=(flag1=flag_&tbl.));
  set &tbl._err;
  keep pasecure flag1;
  run;

  proc sort data=&tbl._err1; by pasecure; run;
  %let sub_out=&sub_out. &tbl._err1;
%end;

data new;
merge &sub_out.;
by pasecure;
run;

%mend data;
%data(sub=Alg Bio Lit);
```

Notice that I rename your `flag1` variables because they cannot all have the same name if you want to keep them in your merged dataset.

Comment: Hi, code-only answers are discouraged here; explanations of how/why are valued significantly over code (I'd rather see an answer with no code than one with basically only code).  Teach a user to fish and all that.